# What is the equivalent Drupal 7 module for the W3 Total Cache Wordpress plugin?

Tags: performance, drupal, caching, drupal-7

Looking for modules to speed up a Drupal 7 with Drupal Commerce install on a Media Temple Virtual host.

Open topic!

Comment: i flagged as belonging on: drupal.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Boost is the one you are searching for.

http://drupal.org/project/boost

Comment: Yah - I saw this but no stable release on 7.

Same with Varnish.

Any others out there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

make sure you configure the core cache for D7 which is better than D6. You can also use varnish in front of D7 without the varnish module (the module just helps facilitate when to invalidate some blobs and do some monitoring from within drupal).

However, unless you get creative with serverside includes, Varnish and other static cache systems probably won't help you much with a commerce system (once someone is logged in you can't do as much simple caching), so I would look at memcached which does have a recommended D7 release and is close to a full 1.0 release ( http://drupal.org/project/memcache )